# Regarding Lagging of my react page on intergreating Material React Table

Tags: javascript, reactjs, grid, react-table

I integrated Material React Table's table in React project. The integration made my entire page laggy. The input boxes are lagging in loading the values to them.
I am using javascrit

I tried if the issue is due to api calls but it was not